# "strtol" return different values

Tags: c++, eclipse

Could someone help me to understand why I see different output for a same input? output of "n" is 2147483647 that is incorrect. why?

-------- output ----------

```
FF
FF
FF
FF

FFFFFF
16777215
16777215
```

--------- code ---------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    string s="FF FF FF FF";
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> begin(ss);
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> end;
    std::vector<std::string> vstrings(begin, end);
    std::copy(vstrings.begin(), vstrings.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
    printf("\n");

    string str2=vstrings[0]+vstrings[1]+vstrings[2]+vstrings[3];
    cout<<str2<<endl;
    unsigned long n = strtol( str2.c_str(), 0, 16 );
    cout<<n<<endl;

    string s1 = "ffffffff";
    unsigned long n1 = strtoul( s1.c_str(), 0, 16 );
    cout << n1 << endl;
```

Comment: Correction! output of "n" = 2147483647, output of "n1" = 4294967295. if input="ffffff", both outputs are same.

Comment: It's better is you make a corrections by editing the question text.

Comment: You are using two different functions, `strtoul` works on unsigned values, `strtol` works on signed values. If you are using Windows where `long` has 32 bits, you have problem, because `FFFFFFFF` as signed is -1. If you want to get correct first result use `strtoll` and save result in `long long`.

Comment: a typo: `strtol` and `strtoul` ? If it's intended, `FFFFFFFF`is not presentable fully by `strtol`,because it's bigger than the maximum value of `signed long` on your platform.

Comment: Sorry, i overlooked the different functions. must be careful next time

Answer (score 1):

`strtol` and `strtoul` are different functions that behave in different ways and return different things.

If you call `strtol` on `0xFFFFFFFF` then the result might (depending on platform) be beyond the range of what a `long` can hold. As you can see from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol), in that case the value returned will be `LONG_MAX` and `errno` will be set.

When you call `strtoul`, however, `0xFFFFFFFF` will probably be in range on most platforms and will just return you the correct result.